# Deletion in List | Spring

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags

I am getting the list as follows:

```
<table border=1 align="center" width="90%" id="skilltableId">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Skill</th>
                <th>Levels</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="agentSkills" id="agentSkills">
            <core:forEach items="${personForm.skillList}" var="skill" varStatus="status">
                <tr  id='${skill.skillDbid}' class='trClass' onclick="selectSkill(this.id)">

                    <td>${skill.skillName}
                    <form:hidden path="skillList[${status.index}].skillName" id="hiddenSkillname"/>
                      </td>
                     <form:hidden path="skillList[${status.index}].skillDbid" id="hiddenSkilldbid"/>
                    <td colspan="2">${skill.skillLevel}
                    <form:hidden path="skillList[${status.index}].skillLevel" id="hiddenSkillLevel"/>
                     </td>
                </tr>
            </core:forEach>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="delBtn">
```

Sample output:

```
Skill                Levels

English                   5
Hindi                     4
Telugu                    8
```

The data will be listed in a table format as in above format. If I click the 'tr' it should highlight the row and then after clicking the button (id="delBtn") that particular data should be deleted from the list. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it would be something like that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Click Event on the tr
    $(".trClass").click(function() {
        //Remove the highlight if already selected
        if($(this).attr("data-selected") == "selected") {
            $(this).css("background-color", "InitialColor");
            $(this).attr("data-selected", "notSelected");
            return;
        }

        // Highlight the tr
        $(this).css("background-color", "ColorYourWant");
        $(this).attr("data-selected", "selected");
    });

    //Click Event on the button
    $("#delBtn").click(function() {
        // Delete the tr
        $('tr[data-selected="selected"]').remove();

        //AJAX can be add here if you want to do something like deleting the row from the database
    });

})
```

If you are using this solution, you can remove `onclick="selectSkill(this.id)` on your `tr`.

Comment: i tried using script..it is getting deleted from the table.but it should be removed from the list also..how to do that..

Comment: Which list are you talking about. The Java List? Are you fetching the list from the database?

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me..similarly i have an situation where i would like to add one row from another jsp..how to do that..the script which i tried is adding,but not binding to the list..here is a sample code.

```
var table = window.parent.parent.parent.personTabs.document.getElementById("skilltableId").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    //alert("table:"+table);
        //var tbody = window.parent.parent.parent.personTabs.document.getElementById("skillRow");
        //alert(tbody);
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        //alert(row);
        var data1 = document.createElement("td");
        //alert(data1);
        data1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("selecetedValue").value));
        alert(window.parent.parent.parent.personTabs.document.getElementById("hiddenSkillname").value);
        window.parent.parent.parent.personTabs.document.getElementById("hiddenSkillname").value=window.parent.parent.parent.personTabs.document.getElementById("hiddenSkillname").value+"\t"+document.getElementById("selecetedValue").value;
        var data2 = document.createElement("td");
        //alert(data2);
        data2.appendChild (document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("type").value));
        window.parent.parent.parent.personTabs.document.getElementById("hiddenSkillLevel").value=window.parent.parent.parent.personTabs.document.getElementById("hiddenSkillLevel").value+"\t"+document.getElementById("type").value;
        var data3 = document.createElement("td");
        //alert(data2);
        data3.appendChild (document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("commonDbid").value));
        window.parent.parent.parent.personTabs.document.getElementById("hiddenSkilldbid").value=window.parent.parent.parent.personTabs.document.getElementById("hiddenSkilldbid").value+"\t"+document.getElementById("commonDbid").value;
        row.appendChild(data1);
        row.appendChild(data2);
        //row.appendChild(data3);
        table.appendChild(row);
        window.parent.parent.document.getElementById("popup1").style.display="none";
```

Comment: Hi jean ur code worked.but adding new row didnt worked.. i have a same table where i have three buttons(Add,Del,Edit)[first jsp].when i click the 'add button' i am showing one popup,where two textboxes and a button is there[another jsp].those two values in the textboxes should be added to the list ie.,first jsp and a new row should be generated.how to do that..? and also when i click the newly generated row onclick function should work..thanks in adv.!!

Comment: @Hi jean...i need to process the list which i got in jsp..like i want to add to the list object in a new row,delete a row,edit a row..those should happen without going to the controller..i m trying .no success til now..let me know..thanks in adv..